# Turtle variable registration not working as intended

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model that counts each interaction of all turtles and presents them in a monitor.
My code works, except not as intended. I get way too many variable registrations.

I am somewhat inexperienced with Netlogo. I have already tested my code with as little and as many turtles as possible, yet the variable registration seems to happen on every tick for all turtles regardless of their location.

```
to interact

  ask citizens with [alerted?] [
    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [panicked?]
        [ set mood mood - 20
          set total-contagions total-contagions + 1]

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [calm?]
        [ set mood mood + 10
          set total-contagions total-contagions + 1]

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [alerted?]
        [ set mood mood - 1
          set total-contagions total-contagions + 1]

    ]
    ask citizens with [calm?] [

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [alerted?]
      [set mood mood - 5
        set total-contagions total-contagions + 1 ]

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [panicked?]
      [set mood mood - 15
        set total-contagions total-contagions + 1 ]

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [calm?]
      [set mood mood + 5
        set total-contagions total-contagions + 1]
   ]

  ask citizens with [panicked?] [
    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [panicked?]
      [ set mood mood - 3
        set total-contagions total-contagions + 1 ]

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [alerted?]
      [ set total-contagions total-contagions + 1 ]

    if any? citizens in-radius 3 with [calm?]
      [ set total-contagions total-contagions + 1 ]

   ]

   end
```

What I need to achieve is every interaction to be counted as one and not many times over the course of the simulation. Furthermore, I need every interaction to be counted only when turtles are in close proximity with each other.

Comment: Imagine that there is an alerted citizen with several other citizens within radius 3. What do you want to happen if some of those close citizens are panicked and some are calm? At the moment, two changes to mood occur and I imagine that's where your extra registrations are happening.

Comment: To help understand the problem, in that case, I need each individual turtle's variable that came into contact with each other to change. Let's say there exist three turtles, one alerted, one panicked and one calm and they come in contact with each other. In the "alerted" turtle's case, if all meet at the same time, I need its mood to be reduced by 10 (-20 + 10). In the "panicked" turtle's case, its mood won't change, since the other two turtles (calm and alerted) won't effect its mood. When all three meet together, I need the "total contagions" variable to go up by 3. I hope this made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is that you increase contagions in every block. Look at your example from the comments with 1 panicked, 1 calm and 1 alerted and the three meet. Take the perspective of the alerted turtle (the first part of your code):

- first test: yes, there is a panicked nearby, so the mood changes and contagions increments
- second test: yes, there is also a calm nearby, so the mood changes and contagions increases AGAIN
- third test: yes, there is an alerted nearby (itself), so again contagions increments

The first correction is to change your tests to `if any? other citizens ...` because including `other` excludes itself from the test.

The second correction is really a logic issue rather than a coding issue, you need to work out what you really want to count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I did not manage to solve my problem completely, it helped me to tackle the issue at an acceptable level and carry on with the rest of my model. Have a nice day.